# eas build main.jsbundle "no such file or directory"

Tags: ios, build, eas

```
Copying   ./main.jsbundle ➜ ../../../Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle
```

> error: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle: No such file or directory (in target 'awsgymprivate' from project 'awsgymprivate')

```
› Copying   ios/awsgymprivate/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist
› Compiling awsgymprivate » SplashScreen.storyboard
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   CpResource /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/awsgymprivate-arsazrrfzqfpbbfjwzimmjlfgbfl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/awsgymprivate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/awsgymprivate.app/main.jsbundle /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/main.jsbundle (in target 'awsgymprivate' from project 'awsgymprivate')
▸ (1 failure)
2024-02-07 22:36:13.003 xcodebuild[1998:7885] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I have tried

1. `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`
   [image]
2. `(Xcode) -Build Phases -> Bundle React Native code and images`, change to

   cd $PROJECT_DIR/..
   export NODE_BINARY=node
   ./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh

but still error happen. Please help